# Calculate tax for after discount amount Odoo 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

In odoo pos i set 'Allow Global Discount'. I defined a product as `Discount` set both customer tax and vendor tax as Null.  In pos order, selected multiple products, odoo automatically calculated `Total Amount & Tax`.

But when i apply `Discount` the tax remain same.I think the tax amount should be calculate only for remaining amount.

Example:

```
Subtotal(Untaxed Amount) = 1500

Tax Amount               =   25

Total                    = 1525
```

If i apply 100 % Discount, the total amount will be 0.00 and tax remain same as 25.

Is it bug?

How can i calculate tax for remaining amount?

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Odoo, filed here

[Odoo GitHub issue 14371](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/14371)

From the discussion, Odoo doesn't seem to want to fix this as it does not seem to be an issue with them. If you're familiar with python, you might want to take a look into the code, or switch to a different(probably commercial) module for offering discounts.

EDIT:

Working on this ofr a friend, I found a workaround.

You have to find teh addons directory for Odoo on your install, and edit this file:

`addons/pos_discount/static/src/js/discount.js`

Thn go to line 45 which says

`var discount = - pc / 100.0 * order.get_total_with_tax();`

Change this to

`var discount = - pc / 100.0 * order.get_total_without_tax();`

Save this file. Now edit your discount product, and assign the same taxes that your products have. Restart Odoo service and test.

This was tested with Odoo 11, so your mileage may vary on other versions. Also, if your products have different taxes, this might not work for you properly.